# How to show there's a measurable set $K\subseteq[0,1]$ such that $\chi_K$ is everywhere discontinuous in $[0,1]\setminus N$ for any null set $N$?

Tags: real-analysis

I've been struggling with this homework problem for a while.  I think I've found some constraints on $K$, but I have no idea how to create a set satisfying them.

I think $K$ has to have:

1. Both $K$ and $[0,1]\setminus K$ are dense, to ensure $\chi_K$ is everywhere dense in $[0,1]$ to begin with.
2. $m(K) \neq 0$ and $m([0,1]\setminus K) \neq 0$, so that we can't easily make $\chi_K$ constant by just removing either set.
3. $K$ measurable, of course.

Did I miss a constraint, or is any of these wrong?

And how in the world could I possibly find a $K$ satisfying all these?  It's obviously not the Cantor set or the rationals or the irrationals, so what could it be?

Or am I entirely missing the point and this should be an existence proof?

Comment: Why not irrationals?

Comment: @RobertW. that function is continuous *everywhere* on $[0,1] \setminus \chi_{\mathbf Q}$.

Comment: Oh. I misread the title.

Comment: I'm wondering if it is stated incorrectly.

Comment: [Fat Cantor Sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) may be helpful (though they themselves will not work).